# How do I duplicate item when using jquery sortable?

Tags: jquery, list, drag-and-drop, duplicates, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using this method http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists to connect two lists that i have. I want to be able to drag from list A to list B but when the item is dropped, i need to keep the original one still in list A. I checked the options and events but I believe there is nothing like that. Any approaches?

Comment: Good question odle. I had a hard time with the docs on this as well.

Comment: Had a hard time finding a solution. Good question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For a beginning, [have a look at this](http://jsfiddle.net/v265q/), and read @Erez answer, too.

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortable1").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        remove: function (event, ui) {
            ui.item.clone().appendTo('#sortable2');
            $(this).sortable('cancel');
        }
    }).disableSelection();

    $("#sortable2").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: The downside of this approach is that the order of $('#sortable2') is not preserved. Ex. if you drop an item into $('#sortable2') at the top of the list, this solution will render the dropped item at the bottom of the list. Erez's answer below does preserve the dropped position and was a better solution in my use case.

Answer (score 90):

```
$("#sortable1").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    forcePlaceholderSize: false,
    helper: function (e, li) {
        copyHelper = li.clone().insertAfter(li);
        return li.clone();
    },
    stop: function () {
        copyHelper && copyHelper.remove();
    }
});
$(".connectedSortable").sortable({
    receive: function (e, ui) {
        copyHelper = null;
    }
});
```

Comment: This approach is preferable to Thorsten's since this one preserves the order of the original list.

Comment: Works perfectly! This really should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Much better answer than the one that is marked correct. This copies and preserves the order.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is what exactly I'm looking for. And for extra information, removing `insertAfter(li)` from `copyHelper = li.clone().insertAfter(li);` will not create a copy in original list. In case you want to duplicate the item to more than one list, but not the original one.

Answer (score 29):

Erez' solution works for me, but I found its lack of encapsulation frustrating. I'd propose using the following solution to avoid global variable usage:

```
$("#sortable1").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",

    helper: function (e, li) {
        this.copyHelper = li.clone().insertAfter(li);

        $(this).data('copied', false);

        return li.clone();
    },
    stop: function () {

        var copied = $(this).data('copied');

        if (!copied) {
            this.copyHelper.remove();
        }

        this.copyHelper = null;
    }
});

$("#sortable2").sortable({
    receive: function (e, ui) {
        ui.sender.data('copied', true);
    }
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v265q/190/

Comment: Using a hidden placeholder in the first list will give it the common dragged from the exact position effect like so http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/v265q/320/

Answer (score 9):

I know this is old, but I could not get Erez's answer to work, and Thorsten's didn't cut it for the project I need it for. This seems to work exactly how I need:

```
$("#sortable2, #sortable1").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    remove: function (e, li) {
        copyHelper = li.item.clone().insertAfter(li.item);
        $(this).sortable('cancel');
        return li.item.clone();
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: yes this solution is better because it uses li.item so it can be used with multiple elements. Thank you it helped me.

Comment: Actually  `return li.item.clone();` is not even needed in my case

Comment: Are you around and can you tell me how to clone multiple items https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/8sfx1z9b/

Answer (score 7):

The answer of abuser2582707 works best for me.
Except one error: You need to change the return to

```
return li.item.clone();
```

So it should be:

```
$("#sortable2, #sortable1").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    remove: function (e, li) {
        li.item.clone().insertAfter(li.item);
        $(this).sortable('cancel');
        return li.item.clone();
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Erez's solution but for connecting 2 sortable portlets (basis was the portlet example code from http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets), the toggle on the clone would not work. I added the following line before 'return li.clone();' to make it work.

```
copyHelper.click(function () {
    var icon = $(this);
    icon.toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick");
    icon.closest(".portlet").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
});
```

This took me a while to figure out so I hope it helps someone.