# How can I change the newly dropped item in a JQuery UI sortable or how can I know when the dropped item is new?

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm creating a simple assembly language editor in javascript using JQuery UI. I want to be able to drag instructions from an instruction set and drop them into a program which is sortable.

However I need to show the instruction set as just a list of words (opcodes) and then have them change when dropped in order to have editable parameters (operands).

I tried using a custom helper in the draggable instruction set, but although the instruction changes as soon as it is dragged, it will revert to its old form after it is dropped. Now I'm trying to use drop events in the sortable such as "update" in order to update the DOM of the dropped instruction but I can't find a way to only do this when the instruction is new and not just being reordered.

In short, I need know how I can change the DOM of newly dropped items in a sortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [receive](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive) event?

```
$('#list1').sortable({
  connectWith:'#list2',
  receive: function(e, ui){
    ui.item.addClass('new');
  }
});
```

I created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jHRFq/) to show how to add a class to the element being received.

If you drag an element from `#list2` onto `#list1` it gets a new class/blue background. But if you simply reorder an existing item it does nothing. Reordering the new item will also do nothing to it, ie. it will keep the class/blue background color. I chose to add a class because it's easier as an example but you can do whatever you need to, like create an input field to enter operands, once the item is received.

Does that help?

Edit: 
If you need to keep the original element in the list try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jHRFq/1/) out

```
$('#list2').sortable({
  connectWith:'#list1',
  remove: function(e, ui){
    ui.item.clone().appendTo('#list1').addClass('new');
    $(this).sortable('cancel');
  }
});
```

It adds the item at the end of the list (append) but I'm sure that with a little bit of research you can figure out how to place it right.

Comment: Thank you but the instruction set from where instructions are to be dragged needs to remain unchanged. You must be able to drag the same instruction as many times as you like.

Comment: Edited my post to include an option to keeping the original element in the list.
[This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940390/how-do-i-duplicate-item-when-using-jquery-sortable) might help you with the positioning of the new item on the opcode/operand list: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940390/how-do-i-duplicate-item-when-using-jquery-sortable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940390/how-do-i-duplicate-item-when-using-jquery-sortable).

Comment: Oh so rather than connect the sortable to a droppable as is shown in the jQuery UI example, you connect two sortables and make one of them recreate the dragged items. Am I understanding this right?

Comment: yes, that is the approach I took in my example but as is often the case it's not likely to be the only one. The link I posted in my previous comment has more info about it and explains how to recreate the item in another list while preserving the position, rather than dumping it at the bottom.

Comment: hey, one more question. What if I don't want to let the instruction set to be reordered?

Comment: @mtanti You can use the [update event](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) like so:
`update: function(e, ui){
  $(this).sortable('cancel');
}`
It will cancel the sort event on the list where you add it.