# jQuery + UI and nestedSortable, clone does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I try to make this example (http://jsfiddle.net/jhogervorst/Ge7eK/9/) work with cloning list elements from left menu to right. There is already helper: 'clone', but it doesn't work =\

```
$('ol.sortable').nestedSortable({
    disableNesting: 'no-nest',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    handle: 'div',
    helper: 'clone',
    items: 'li',
    maxLevels: 3,
    opacity: .6,
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    revert: 250,
    tabSize: 25,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    toleranceElement: '> div',

    /* The magic tric: */
    connectWith: '.sortable'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact it does work but not in the way you're thinking, I assume...

The clone in *sortable* «disappears» when the action is completed and it's quite logic, doesn't it? Because if you want an element to stay at its «initial source» and being copied elsewhere at the same time **it's not a sort but a drag**.

It seems you're trying to achieve something like the demo of this page:

- http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable

(*...if you doesn't want to work with 2 functions like the demo above I suggest you to use a callback at the end of the action to manually clone and append your element to its «initial source»*).

But if you only want to see it *while* you're sorting your element just add some styles to «placeholder» and it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

[How do I duplicate item when using jquery sortable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940390/how-do-i-duplicate-item-when-using-jquery-sortable)

nestedSortable is just extension of jQuery UI sortable, so you can use same functions