# how to keep a draggable object in its place, after being dragged also?

Tags: jquery, html, css

There is a column for drag and drop in my code.
What I want is that , when I drag an item, it should get dragged
but its coPY should remain itself there.

$('#example-1-3 .sortable-list').sortable({
        connectWith: '#example-1-4 .sortable-list'
    });

list1
aa
bb
cc

list2
zz
xx
mm

so i want to drag aa to list2 , but aa should remain in the list.

```
$('#example-1-3 .sortable-list').sortable({
   connectWith: '#example-1-4 .sortable-list'
});

<div class="dhe-example-section" id="ex-1-3">
<div class="dhe-example-section-content">
<!-- BEGIN: XHTML for example 1.3 -->

<div id="example-1-3">

<ul class="sortable-list ui-sortable">
<li class="sortable-item">Deposit INterest</li>
<li class="sortable-item">GDP% of total</li>
<li class="sortable-item">GDP curr($)</li>
<li class="sortable-item">Health exp</li>
</ul>

</div>

<!-- END: XHTML for example 1.3 -->

</div>
</div><br><br>  
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="dhe-example-section" id="ex-1-4">
<div class="dhe-example-section-content" >
<!-- BEGIN: XHTML for example 1.4 -->
<div id="example-1-4">
<div class="column left first">

<ul class="sortable-list ui-sortable"><br>
<li class="sortable-item">Sortable item A</li>
<li class="sortable-item">Sortable item B</li>
</ul>

</div>
</div></div></div>
```

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: @drip
This is the drag gable code.

<div class="dhe-example-section" id="ex-1-3"><div class="dhe-example-section-content">
<!-- BEGIN: XHTML for example 1.3 --><div id="example-1-3"><ul class="sortable-list ui-sortable"><li class="sortable-item">Deposit INterest</li><li class="sortable-item">GDP% of total</li><li class="sortable-item">GDP curr($)</li><li class="sortable-item">Health exp</li></ul></div><!-- END: XHTML for example 1.3 --></div></div><br><br></div></div></div>

Comment: $('#example-1-3 .sortable-list').sortable({
  connectWith: '#example-1-4 .sortable-list'
 });

Comment: Put code in question, not as comment

Comment: <div class="dhe-example-section" id="ex-1-3"><div class="dhe-example-section-content"> <!-- BEGIN: XHTML for example 1.3 --><div id="example-1-3"><ul class="sortable-list ui-sortable"><li class="sortable-item">Deposit INterest</li><li class="sortable-item">GDP% of total</li><li class="sortable-item">GDP curr($)</li><li class="sortable-item">Health exp</li></ul></div><!-- END: XHTML for example 1.3 --></div></div><br><br></div></div></div>

Comment: @A.Wolff
 
$('#example-1-3 .sortable-list').sortable({ connectWith: '#example-1-4 .sortable-list' });

Comment: @A.Wolff
please can u help

Comment: @Voodoo i guess `helper: "clone"` is what you are looking for as in Martin Hansen Lennox's answer

Comment: @A.Wolff
yeah I get that. But where do I put that code. I am new to jquery

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure how you want it to work, can you provide more detail?

If you're using jquery's draggable, you can try something like this?

```
$( "#draggableElement" ).draggable({ helper: "clone" });
```

**Update:**

Are you wanting something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/v265q/

```
$(function() {
        $( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
            remove: function(event, ui) {
                ui.item.clone().appendTo('#sortable2');
                $(this).sortable('cancel');
            }
        }).disableSelection();

    $( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
            connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
        }).disableSelection();
    });
});
```

I didn't create this fiddle btw, it came from the following post - you might want to check it out in full because it has some additional info / suggestions.

[How do I duplicate item when using jquery sortable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940390/how-do-i-duplicate-item-when-using-jquery-sortable)

Comment: I just want , that when I drag and drop the item. It should still remain in its original place.

Comment: Hi Voodoo, it depends on what code you already have. Can you put up a fiddle of your code?  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: $('#example-1-3 .sortable-list').sortable({ connectWith: '#example-1-4 .sortable-list' });