# i have drag divs , i need to know id of divs it dragover it to add drop area after unknown div

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="editor">
            <!-- Here is the draggable section of this ui -->
            <div id="drag-1" class="ui-widget-content d ">
                <span>first dragged</span>
            </div>
            <div id="drag-2" class="ui-widget-content d" >
                <span>second dragged</span>
            </div>
            <div id="drag-3" class="ui-widget-content d">
                <span>third dragged</span>
            </div>     
        </div>
<div id='drop' style="display:none"></div>
```

/*i have three dragged divs  , when i dragged any one i need to know div id  that dragged div will drag over to create drop div after it  */

Comment: Share the fiddle in http://jsfiddle.net/ for the work you have done already.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gkt4bt7x/3/

but i can't add a plugin so i copy paste it into javascript section

Comment: now plugin replace dragged div with dropped div , i need to add drop area after dragged over div  to drop  dragged element on it like as 

http://themeforest.net/item/mantos-responsive-email-with-template-editor/full_screen_preview/9401993

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940390/how-do-i-duplicate-item-when-using-jquery-sortable