# How to keep original list items in place when using jQuery sortable

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

My [JSFiddle located here](http:////jsfiddle.net/patricksharer/4oaanxoq/)

I am using the jQuery function sortable to be able to sort 3 columns. I would like to make it so that whaen a name is grabbed from column 2 or 3 and placed in column 1, the names from 2 and 3 with remain in their current state so that the column stays alphabetized and the same height. I hope I am explaining this correctly. In other words, I want to grab a name from 2 or 3, place it in 1 and have the name still be in 2 or 3.

Comment: Do you have any javascript to add to the jsfiddle?

Comment: Strange. I do and its in there but its not saving.

Comment: @csum it should be working now. I never had this issue before JSFiddl's latest update. Thanks for looking!

Comment: Have you found any other SO posts with examples for copying elements (rather than moving)? It seems you could do that plus disable sorting within columns 2 & 3 to preserve their order.

Comment: @csum I haven't been able to find anything along the lines of what I need. I'm a total beginner when it comes to jQuery so it confuses the hell out of me.

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12659113/3495594 should help with cloning elements. I've adapted the solution only a little to fit your case: http://jsfiddle.net/4oaanxoq/2/.

I set the ul's with id's `sortable1`, `sortable2`, and `sortable3`. The first has class `destinationList`, the others have class `sourceList`.

There is also `.sourceList .source-placeholder { display: none !important; }` in the CSS, which you may or may not want to use.

Note that it does not prevent reordering the items within columns 2 and 3, so you'll still need a solution for that part. Take a look at the events in the [sortable api](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/).

Comment: Awesome, thank you for this! It has definitely sent me down the right direction. Now I just need to figure out how to keep my numbers when a name is placed in a position and make it so I can delete names out of column 1. You rock @csum.