# jQuery UI Draggable + Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Let me give [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/rmSgx/377/): I want to create **colored div's** by dragging them from the left list `.draggable-colors` to the right div `#sortable`.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <ul class="draggable-colors" style="float:left;">
    <li id="draggable-red">Red</li>
    <li id="draggable-green">Green</li>
    <li id="draggable-blue">Blue</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="sortable" style="float:right;">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#sortable").sortable();
$("#draggable-red").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
});
$("#draggable-green").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
});
$("#draggable-blue").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
});
```

So when I start dragging an item from the left list I want a colored div being dragged `<div class="red"></div>` and not an `<li id="draggable-red">Red</li>` so I can create colored div's.

How can I accomplish this using [droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/) and [draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)?

---

EDIT 1:

What I need is something like this (**whatToBeDragged**):

```
$("#draggable-red").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
    whatToBeDragged: "<li id='draggable-red'>Red</li>"
});
```

---

EDIT 2:

Added a helper function to the draggable handler, it fixed the dragging issue but somehow it keeps creating list items and not colored divs. Anyone?

```
$("#draggable-red").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    helper: "<li id='draggable-red'>Red</li>",
    revert: "invalid" 
});
```

Comment: Just to confirm, when I start dragging item type 1 I should see Item 1. And when I drop it onto sortable div. It should add Item 1 into that div?

Comment: Yes @xszaboj that is what I look for.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940390/how-do-i-duplicate-item-when-using-jquery-sortable) might help

Comment: Thank you @AndrewMcghie that seems to help.